# Words starting with "touch"

Tags: meaning, etymology

There are several words in English starting with *touch*, such as touchwood, touchstone, touchline, ect. (a list can be found here : http://www.scrabblefinder.com/starts-with/touch/ )

I would like to know if there is some intuition or some rule that can suggest the meaning of (the majority of) these words. Is it true that majority of this words were formed in the same way?

Comment: The intuition is words which begin with "touch" all derived from the physical, literal act of touching (Google touchstone+etymology, or any other word + etymology, to see what I mean). Beyond that, I'll suggest that there really aren't that many words which begin with "touch", so looking for a governing rule may be overkill.

Comment: @DanBron If you include hyphenated words, [onelook.com](http://www.onelook.com/?w=touch*&ls=a) lists about 80.

Comment: @bib, if you include hyphenated words, there are ∞ possibilities (because the "*morpheme*-*morpheme*" construct  is productive). By contrast, using dict.org to search [multiple dictionaries for the regular expression ^touch\[^ -\]+$](http://www.dict.org/bin/Dict?Form=Dict1&submit=submit&Database=*&Strategy=re&Query=%5Etouch%5B%5E%20-%5D%2B%24) returns about 18 results, of which I'd characterize 8 as the "kind of words" OP is looking for (i.e. *touch* as a prefix for another true morpheme): *touchback*, *touchdown*, *touchhole*, *touchstone*, *touchwood*, *touchline*, *touchpad*, *touchscreen*.

Comment: @DanBron The OED has 95 results for keywords starting with *touch*.  But you really shouldn’t talk about productivity: it seems to splode certain minds around here.

Comment: @tchrist, can you use your fancy OED-grepping tool to see how many are unhyphenated (and not compound)? (Also, was my comment wrong, either technically or philosophically?  You can tell me, I can take it :)

Comment: @DanBron 38 match the pattern `^touch\pL`.

Comment: @tchrist, Cool (and `\pL` is "*a letter, according to some script*"?). Any interesting or otherwise surprising results? (I'm also amused that all the word-counts mentioned so far have `8` in them: `80`, `18`, `8`, and `38`!).

Comment: @Dan *touché* [int.], *ˌtouch-me-ˈnot-ishness* [n.], *ˈtouchant* [prep.], *touch-hole* [n.], *touch-kicking* [v.], *touch-warden* [n.], *touchy-headed* [adj.], and *touchquhare* [n.] which is an old spelling of *toucher*  from Irish and Old Gaelic (Modern Gaelic *tochradh*)  meaning “The marriage portion which a wife brings to her husband; dowry, *dot.”*

Comment: @tchrist I love "touch warden"; the assayer-general, who is responsible for evaluating the purity of precious metals.

Comment: @tchrist Ugh, I hate that the OED always uses _Gaelic_ to mean Scottish Gaelic in particular. (The Irish is not _tochradh_, but _tochra_: the Scots regularised it to the most productive class of verbal nouns, those ending in _-adh_.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet These days I seem to hear *Gallic* used for the Caledonian kind. And I of course typo’d it: it should be ***tocher***  `/ˈtoxər/`.  Has compounds like ***“tocher-fee, -gear; tocher-band,*** a marriage settlement; ***tocher-good,*** property given as tocher or dower.” I can just see someone not knowing typical Scots phonology making *tocher-good* sound like “touch ’er good”. :)

Answer (score 1):

They all have root in the general physical action or state of touch, but the motivation behind each act of touch is so varied that there isn't a single rule of thumb that can provide more specificity.